# How to get a working example of jboss7.1 arquillan test?

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

Since two days, i'm trying to run an example of "Arquillan" Test using jboss 7.1.1 but they are always many errors. Nothing is working like i can read in many tutorial found in the Internet.
Please where i can download a full working example that show how to use Arquillan Test with Jboss7.1.1 ?
Thank

Comment: Just a nice related link:  http://arquillian.org/guides/functional_testing_using_drone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using maven. To get a working example of an Arquillian test with JBoss-7.1.1-Final you can create a new project using the following archetype: `org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-ear-webapp-archetype:7.1.1.Beta1` (this is the most recent version at the time of writing). The test is located in the ejb-module.

Then follow the instructions in `README.md`:

> To run the test in JBoss AS 7, first start a JBoss AS 7 instance. Then, run the
>   test goal with the following profile activated:

```
mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote
```

It's necessary to set `skip` to *false* in `/pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>default</id>
     <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
     <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.3</version>
              <configuration>
                 <skip>false</skip>
...
```

Comment: @Belin Welcome in our community. You might want to mark this question as solved to indicate for others that this is your accepted solution, and maybe upvote this answer if it was helpful ;-)

Comment: Hi Thor how to do that? (marked that a question  is solved) but i think i have already upvoted this answer

Comment: @Belin On the left side of the question there is a checkmark as well as an uparrow (perhaps you don't have enough points to do this).